# Parsing text type log file with values surrounded by double quotes and separated by comma

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell, logfile

I have this log file and I am trying to parse it.
The problem is that the data lines are in the format "value","value", ... and some times "value\"value\"", ...

```
#basepath  D:\XHostMachine\Results
#results   test.res
#fields    TestPlan Script TestCase TestData ErrorCount ErrorText DateTime Elapsed
#delimiter , 
#quote     " \

"D:\XHostMachine\plans\test.pln","D:\XHostMachine\testcases\test.t","rt1","1,\"a\"",1,"[#ERROR#][APPS-EUAUTO1] [error] rt1 t1 ( Screen shot : D:\XTestMachines\Error\[APPS-EUAUTO1] 03-28-14 11-29-22.png)","2014-03-28 11.29.04","0:00:18"
"D:\XHostMachine\plans\test.pln","D:\XHostMachine\testcases\test.t","rt2","1,\"a\"",0,"","2014-03-28 11.29.22","0:00:08"
```

but I'm not able to split the lines using `","` as a delimiter (because `,` might be present inside)

my code is :

```
Function Get-RexLog {
Param ($File)
# Reads the log file into memory.
    Try {
        Get-Content -path $File -ErrorAction Stop | select -skip 6 # skips the first 6 lines
    } Catch {
        Write-Error "The data file is not present" 
        BREAK
    }
} # End: Function Get-RexLog

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

Function Get-Testplan {
Param ($RexLog)
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $RexLog.Count; $i++) {
        $Testcase = $RexLog[$i].Split("`"[,]`"") | ForEach-Object - process {$_.TrimStart('"')}
        $Output = New-Object PSobject -Property @{
            TestPlan   = $Testcase[0]
            Script     = $Testcase[1]
            TestCase   = $Testcase[2]
            TestData   = $Testcase[3]
            ErrorCount = $Testcase[4]
            ErrorText  = $Testcase[5]
            DateTime   = $Testcase[6]
            Elapsed    = $Testcase[7]
        }
    }
} # End: Function Get-Testplan

# -----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Parse the files
$RexLog = Get-RexLog -file "D:\XHostMachine\Results\test.rex"
$Testplan = Get-Testplan -RexLog $RexLog
$Testplan
```

**FINAL EDIT :**
using ConvertFrom-Csv

```
ConvertFrom-Csv -inputobject $RexLog -Header @("TestPlan","Script","TestCase","TestData","ErrorCount","ErrorText","DateTime","Elapsed")
```

Comment: This could easily be done with a regex. Do you want to use a regex as oposed to split?

Comment: @sln Using regex will not be a problem, but I do not know how to implement it. Can you give me a suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: I don't know Powershell regex function calls, but I could give you the regex.

Comment: The format sounds an awful lot like a CSV file. Have you tried passing it through the Import-CSV cmdlet?  (it is designed to handle double quotes around the "data" and still handle the commas. See @Kayasax's answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

powershell can easily process comma separated value text file ( csv ) using the `import-csv` cmdlet.

Look :

```
PS C:\temp> Import-Csv c:\temp\test.csv -Header @("TestPlan","Script","TestCase","TestData","ErrorCount","ErrorText","Da
teTime","Elapsed")


TestPlan   : D:\XHostMachine\plans\test.pln
Script     : D:\XHostMachine\testcases\test.t
TestCase   : rt1
TestData   : 1,\a\""
ErrorCount : 1
ErrorText  : [#ERROR#][APPS-EUAUTO1] [error] rt1 t1 ( Screen shot : D:\XTestMachines\Error\[APPS-EUAUTO1] 03-28-14
             11-29-22.png)
DateTime   : 2014-03-28 11.29.04
Elapsed    : 0:00:18

TestPlan   : D:\XHostMachine\plans\test.pln
Script     : D:\XHostMachine\testcases\test.t
TestCase   : rt2
TestData   : 1,\a\""
ErrorCount : 0
ErrorText  :
DateTime   : 2014-03-28 11.29.22
Elapsed    : 0:00:08
```

Comment: Good answer, except that `TestData` should convert to `1,"a"` instead of `1,\a\""`.